# Probability Distribution Of Random Variable Defined By Gaussian Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I don't have answers to this question
Please let me know if there are mistakes

Problem:

> $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent Gaussian random variables with:
>   $E(X) = 2$
> $E(Y) = −1$
> $E(Z) = 4$
> $Var(X) = 2$
>  $Var(Y) = 1$
>   $Var(Z) = 2$ 
>   
>  If the random variable $W$ is given by $W = 3X + 3Y − Z$
>
> i) Find the mean and variance of $W$
>  ii) Write down the probability
>   distribution for $pW(w)$
>  iii) What is the probability that a sample
>   of $W$ will be between 0 and 5?

Attempt:

i)

\begin{align}
E(W) &= E(3X + 3Y - Z)\\
\ &= E(3X) + E(3Y) - E(Z) \\
\ &= 3E(X) + 3E(Y) - E(Z) \\ 
\ &= 3(2) + 3(-1) - 4\\
\ &= -1 \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
V(W) &= V(3X + 3Y - Z)\\
\ &= V(3X) + V(3Y) - V(Z) \\
\ &= 9V(X) + 9V(Y) - V(Z) \\ 
\ &= 9(2) + 9(1) - 2\\
\ &= 25 \\
\end{align}

ii)

I am not sure how to find $pW(w)$ knowing $W$, $E(W)$ and $V(W)$.

iii)

Given $pW(w)$ from part ii I assume the answer would be:
$P(0 ≤ W ≤ 5) = \int_{0}^5 pW(w) dW$

Thank you

Comment: The variance of $X-Y$, if $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, is the *sum* of the variances, not the difference. You don't subtract (ever), since it comes from $\mathrm{var}(X-Y)=\mathrm{var}(X+(-Y)) = \mathrm{var}(X)+(-1)^2\mathrm{var}(Y)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In part a, you mistakenly subtract the third variance rather than adding it. You know how when you multiply a variable by a constant, the variance gets multiplied by the constant squared? Well, the same goes for $(-1).$ So the variance should be $29,$ not $25$

For part $b$ any sum of independent Gaussians is a Gaussian and a Gaussian is fully characterized by its mean and variance. So we have $W\sim N(-1,29)$ and it has PDF $$f_W(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{58\pi}}e^{-\frac{(w+1)^2}{58}}.$$

Part c looks good too, and now you know what to plug in. It might be easier to write it in terms of the $N(0,1)$ quantity $\frac{W+1}{\sqrt{29}}$. We have $$0<W<5 \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{29}}< \frac{W+1}{\sqrt{29}} <\frac{6}{\sqrt{29}} $$ so the answer should be $$P(1/\sqrt{29} < N(0,1) < 6/\sqrt{29}) = \Phi(6/\sqrt{29})-\Phi(1/\sqrt{29})$$ where $\Phi$ is the standardard normal CDF.

**Note** A previous version mistakenly gave OP an 'all clear' on part (a).

Comment: "Part $a$ looks right." **No**. $\mathrm{var}(X-Y)\neq \mathrm{var}(X)-\mathrm{var}(Y)$ when $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: @ClementC. Hwooops

Comment: This means it should have been: $9(2) + 9(1) + 1(2) = 29$?

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin Yep, wasn't reading closely enough, sorry about that.